# Should we get rid of the tag 'convert'

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is anyone actually interested in the ([convert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convert)) tag? I saw 0 followers, and there are too many data formats to convert from/to for it to make sense to me. For one, why would one assume that a person who is interesting in conversion between video formats would also be interested in conversion between packaging file formats.

Comment: I think it's probably a useful clue to search engines. Otherwise I don't care.

Answer (score 3):

There are currently 17 questions with either [convert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/convert) or [conversion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion). These two tags should be synonyms, by the way. All signs point at making [conversion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion) the displayed name: [Super User](https://superuser.com/tags) has the synonym in this direction; on both U&L and [AU](http://askubuntu.com) `conversion` has more uses; `convert` could connote ImageMagick's `convert`.

I don't see this tag as useful to subscribe to. I can sort of see a use case for it being the sole tag on a question: a question about conversion between two really exotic kinds of files, especially by a new user who doesn't have enough reputation to create a new tag. This tag is definitely useful for searches: if you're looking for a way to convert from a to a particular file format, `[format]` [conversion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conversion) narrows the search a lot more than just `[format]`.

Comment: Sounds good to me.